# Getting rid of margins?

Tags: html, css, padding, margins, skin

So I am working on coding for an art site journal for a friend, and a portion of my code just isn't getting rid of some margins/padding that I fear might be part of the main site's coding in the body or something, so it would be something I would need to manually override. [This is what I am working on.](http://hvalla.deviantart.com/blog/622339097/) That journal skin. The rocks towards the bottom are supposed to be flush with the edges of the journal, but no matter what I try they just won't do what I want.

This is the coding I have this far, which isn't a lot:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="contentholder"></div><div class="rockfooter"></div>  
</div>
```

As well as:

```
.gr-body {
background: url(http://orig14.deviantart.net/8b57/f/2016/279/f/5/frontpagebackground_by_wulfghast-dak5apt.jpg);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #1c1119;
color: #545454; }

.header {
background-image: url(http://s10.postimg.org/bvl7xjjbd/branchborder.png);
background-position: top center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
 margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 20%;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
height: 873px;
width: 74%;
display: block; }

.contentholder {
width: 68%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: -800px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px #0a0a0a;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px #0a0a0a;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px #0a0a0a;
background-color: #50463b;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
display: block; }

.rockfooter {
background: url(http://s17.postimg.org/is79jxd3z/footer3_by_wulfghast_dakd92b_1.png);
height: 1000px;
width: 100%;
background-position: bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: -985px;
position: relative;
z-index: 4; }

.bottom {
display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

On that particular page you shared, your rock

```
<div class=body>
```

is inside a

```
<div class=text>
```

has padding around it.

See if you can't get rid of that padding, it'll make it flush with the sides.

Comment: this is true...you might want to add the solution " .text{padding: 0px;}" your answer for the OP to try

Comment: That looks like that worked! I never even thought to inspect it through my browser. Thanks!

Comment: No problem!  Always remember to inspect through the browser first, you'll often find something odd messing things up you didn't expect!

Answer (score 0):

You can reset general definitions with:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```